# What are some design errors that lead to hard-to-debug code?

Tags: language-design, implementation

There are some design features in programming languages that make code written in the language difficult to debug (e.g. C's default fallthrough behavior).

So it would be helpful to make a list of these design errors, so that language designers can avoid it while designing a language.

Comment: This question is just too broad currently to work well in the model of the site. If you can narrow it down to a more concrete question then you can [edit] and reopen it. For example, at the least it'd be necessary to have a firm concept of what hard-to-debug meant in order to evaluate answers. "What are some ..." is generally not a productive format either, so it would be good to narrow that down too. Have a look at the [help/on-topic] for more on the sorts of questions that work well here.

Comment: I agree that as it stands is too broad for the SE format but I also think it is useful line of questioning (not necessarily a single question) if we can phrase it better.
So I've asked on meta - https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/what-would-be-a-better-way-to-ask-this-question

As it stands it might be better to ask on [r/programminglangages](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammingLanguages/hot/)

Comment: The fallthrough thing in C is a good thing - it keeps the user from repeating the same code over and over for different cases.  Of course, regex switches (see https://vovkos.github.io/jancy/language/regex_switches.html ) would fix that.